# Como bloquear o acesso em uma pagina pela url

Tags: php

Preciso bloquear o acesso de uma pagina em Php diretamente acessada pela url

Comment: Fecharam sendo que é duplicata mds... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207034/bloquear-p%C3%A1ginas-via-url/207047#207047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com esse código tu impede o acesso direto:

```
if (strcmp(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), basename(__FILE__)) === 0) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Queria entender a cabecinha dos colegas...
O autor da pergunta marcou a resposta como a melhor.
Mesmo assim sempre tem quem "não gostou" e negativa.

Meu caro, se a resposta está errada, ponha a resposta certa, informe isso. Apresente solução melhor. Deve ter. Esse é um script que ajuda. Com certeza há solução mais robusta. Mas negativar sem dar feedback é muita babaquice.