# Bloquear páginas via url

Tags: php, session, url

A página restrita está bloqueada para acesso via url, porém quero deixar o aviso na tela de login. Por exemplo: ao digitar o endereço da página empresarial.php na url, o sistema direciona para a tela de login e exibe a mensagem FAÇA LOGIN PARA ACESSAR abaixo do formulário.
Segue abaixo todo o código.

**Login**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <form method="POST" action="login/valida.php">
        <h2>Área Restrita</h2>
    <label>Login</label>
        <input name="email_cli" type="email" autofocus required placeholder="Email">
    <label>Senha</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha_cli" placeholder="Senha (seu CPF)" required maxlength="11"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="botao_cadastro">Acessar</button>
    </form>
    <h4 style="color: red">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
            echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
            unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
        }?>
    </h4>
    <h4 style="color: green">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
            echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
            unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
        }
        ?>
    </h4>
    <?php
    // Aqui ficaria sua mensagem, por exemplo
    if (isset($_SESSION['erro_acesso'])) {
    ?>
    <h4>Faça o login para acessar.</h4>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </html>
```

**valida.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start(); 
    //Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados   
    include_once("conexao.php");    
    //O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
    if((isset($_POST['email_cli'])) && (isset($_POST['senha_cli']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email_cli']); 
    //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha_cli']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE email_cli = '$usuario' && senha_cli = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id_cli'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome_cli'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['nivel'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email_cli'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: ../basico.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: ../profissional.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
            header("Location: ../avancado.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "4"){
            header("Location: ../empresarial.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['erro_acesso'] = "Faça o login para acessar";
            header("Location: ../login.php");
        }
       //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
       //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
       }else{    
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: ../login.php");
        }
    //O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
    }else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    };
    ?>
```

**conexao.php**

```
    <?php

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "clientes_db";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
}      
?>
```

**verifica_acesso.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    function verifica_nivel($nivel_de_acesso) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId']) || $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] != $nivel_de_acesso) {
    $_SESSION['erro_acesso'] = 1;
    header('Location: ../login.php');
    exit();
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Tu quer bloquear acesso direto á um arquivo pela url? por exemplo: tu tem um arquivo de `connection.class.php` e tu não quer que o usuário acesse direto o arquivo?

Comment: Sim. O site é simples e o conteúdo não é algo preocupante. Apenas quero impedir que seja acessado pela url.

Comment: Vou publicar a resposta;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você poderia utilizar o nível de acesso dele para não acessar certos tipos de arquivos.

*Editando o código conforme sua edição na pergunta.*

**verifica_acesso.php**

```
session_start();
function verifica_nivel($nivel_de_acesso) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId']) || $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] != $nivel_de_acesso) {
        $_SESSION['erro_acesso'] = 1;
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Coloque no inicio das páginas onde você deseja verificar se o nível de acesso é permitido para a área.

Usando em **empresarial.php**

```
include_once "verifica_acesso.php";
verifica_nivel(4);
```

No **login.php** ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<form method="POST" action="login/valida.php">
<h2>Área Restrita</h2>
<?php
// Aqui ficaria sua mensagem, por exemplo
if (isset($_SESSION['erro_acesso'])) {
?>
<h4>Faça o login para acessar.</h4>
<?php
}
?>
<label>Login</label>
<input name="email_cli" type="email" autofocus required placeholder="Email">
<label>Senha</label>
<input type="password" name="senha_cli" placeholder="Senha (seu CPF)" required maxlength="11"><br>
<button type="submit" class="botao_cadastro">Acessar</button>
</form>
<h4 style="color: red">
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
}
?>
</h4>
<h4 style="color: green">
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
}
?>
</h4>
<h4 style="color: green">
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['restrito'])){
echo $_SESSION['restrito'];
unset($_SESSION['restrito']);
}
?>
</h4>
</html>
```

E no **valida.php** após a confirmação de existência do usuário e senha correta:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['erro_acesso'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['erro_acesso']);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Acho que isto mesmo que ele quer... boa thiago

Comment: Thiago. Me ajudou demais.
Agora gostaria de dar uma implementada. Vou alterar a pergunta.

Comment: Editei a resposta @Turkish. Valeu Guilherme!

Comment: Thiago. Retorna a página branca e não redireciona. Será algum erro de array?

Comment: @Turkish você está colocando o header corretamente, dessa forma: `header("Location: ../login.php");` ? Pois no meu código foi só para exemplificar.

Comment: Sim... coloquei. Até que se estivesse errado daria erro 404, só que ele permanece na página empresarial.php mas com a tela branca.

Comment: @Turkish estranho, fiz os testes aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Só dá este problema na área empresarial?

Comment: Em todas as páginas. Alterei o código de como está.

Comment: Fiz mais alguns testes e não encontrei o erro. Poderia postar o código da área empresarial para dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 0):

Tente este código:

```
$Page_Request = strtolower(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$Page_File = strtolower(basename(__FILE__));
if ($Page_Request == $Page_File)
{
    exit("Acesso negado.");
} else {
   return true;
}
```

Ou você pode usar um `header` para home.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ele bloqueou o acesso via url, porém também bloqueou ao tentar o login.

Comment: Fiz uma edição tente, se o `return true` não funcionar tente `return $page_file`. Ou então usar `.htaccess` para fazer isto :(

Comment: Nenhum dos dois funcionou. Vou tentar com o .htaccess e posto o resultado. Valeu.