# sobre form de login com session (usuario desabilitado) tratamento

Tags: php, html, mvc, formulário, login

Olá , boa tarde ,eu gostaria de saber como faço para o sistema de login não deixar logar o administrador que não estiver habilitado  (nivel==5) já tentei de tudo , e  código que estou mexendo é muito misturado , queria que fizesse a mesma coisa quando a pessoa escreve senha errada ,porem com um aviso diferente e fora da sessão

```html
if ($_SESSION ['s_logado']) {
 
 // BLOCO PARA RECARREGAR A PÁGINA NO MÓDULO ADMIN QUANDO FOR SELECIONADO NOVO TEMA
 if (isset ( $_GET ['LOAD'] ) && $_GET ['LOAD'] == 'ADMIN') {
  $PARAM = "&LOAD=ADMIN";
  $marca = "ADMIN";
 } else
  $PARAM = "";
 
 
 print "<tr>";
 
 print "<td style=\"width:100%;\" id='centro2'><iframe class='frm_centro' src='" . $sisPath . "" . $sistem . "'  name='centro' align='center' width='100%' height='77%' frameborder='0' STYLE='{border-bottom: thin solid #999999;}'></iframe></td>";
 print "</tr>";
} else {

 echo '<div class="container">'; 
 $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 
 // Formulário de Login
 
 
  
?>


 <form name='logar' method='post' action='<?php print"".$commonPath."login.php?".session_id ()."";?>' onSubmit=\"return valida()\">
 <div class='container_12 info'>
  <div class='grid_8'> <!-- Inicio da Nova DIV -->
   <h1>Central de Chamados <?php echo NOME_CENTRAL_ATENDIMENTO; ?></h1>
   <br><h3 align='left'>Informações</h3>
   <div class='menu'>
    <ul style="padding-top: 5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important">
     <li align='left'><p>Sistema para auxiliar no gerenciamento de chamados do CTIC. <p>Para ter acesso ao sistema, você precisa de um usuário <p>cadastrado no SIG (<a href='http://sipac.***.edu.br' target='_blank'>acesso ao SIG</a>) </p></li>
     <li><p>A ** nunca pede confirmação de seus dados e senhas<p> via email.</p></li>
     <li><p>A senha de acesso é pessoal e intransferível.</p></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <h3 style="padding-bottom:10px">Seu IP é: <?php echo str_replace(":",".",$ip); ?></h3>
   <h3 align='left'>Dúvidas</h3>
   <p>Entre em contato através dos nossos canais de atendimento.</p>
   <table style="vertical-align: center">
   <tr><td><img src="includes/imgs/email.jpg" width="20px" height="20px"></td><td><a href="mailto:<?php echo EMAIL_CENTRAL_ATENDIMENTO; ?>"><?php echo EMAIL_CENTRAL_ATENDIMENTO; ?></a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><img src="includes/imgs/telefone.jpg" width="20px" height="20px"></td><td><?php echo TELEFONE_CENTRAL_ATENDIMENTO; ?></td></tr>
<!--    <tr><td><img src="includes/imgs/spark.png" width="20px" height="20px"></td><td>Atendimento CTIC (Spark)</td></tr> -->
   <tr><td><a href="https://ctic.**.edu.br" target="_blank"><img src="includes/imgs/site.png" width="20px" height="20px"></a></td><td><a href="<?php echo SITE_CENTRAL_ATENDIMENTO; ?>" target="_blank">Portal</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="https://wiki.***.edu.br" target="_blank"><img src="includes/imgs/wiki-icon.png" width="20px" height="20px"></a></td><td><a href="https://wiki.***.edu.br" target="_blank">WIKI Unifesspa</a></td></tr>
   </table>
 
  </div>
  <div class='grid_4' > <!-- Início Form de Login -->
   <?php 
   
  
    if (isset ( $_GET ['inv'] )) {
     if ($_GET ['inv'] == "1") {
     $aviso =TRANS ( 'ERR_LOGON' ) ;
      print "<div style='margin:0 auto; width:240px; padding:10px;'><center><label ><br><font color='red'>" . $aviso . "</font></label></center></div>";
     }
    }
    if (isset ( $_GET ['usu'] )) {
     $typedUser = $_GET ['usu'];
    } else {
     $typedUser = "";
    }
   
   ?>
   <div style='margin:0 auto;margin-right:15px; width:180px; padding:10px;'>
    <img src = 'helpdesk.png'>
      </div>
   <h2 align='center'>Área de acesso</h2>
   <div style='margin:0 auto; width:180px; padding:0px;'>
       <div style='height:-3px;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#ccc;margin-top:5px;'></div>
          <div style='height:-3px;'>
     <label  id='label_user' class='input_login' for='idLogin' style='display:block;'></label>
     <input class='input_l2' type='text' name='login' value='<?php print $typedUser ?>' id='idLogin' placeholder='Usuario' tabindex='1' onkeydown=\"Hide('label_user','idLogin');\" onblur=\"Show('label_user','idLogin');\">
     <br><br>
     <label  id='label_pass' class='input_login' for='idSenha' style='display:block;'></label>
     <input class='input_l2' type='password' name='password' id='idSenha' placeholder='Senha' tabindex='2' onkeydown=\"Hide('label_pass','idSenha');\" onblur=\"Show('label_pass','idSenha')>
          </div>
    <div style='height:30px; margin-top:5px; text-align:center' >
     <input type='submit' style='float:center' class='blogin' value='<?php print TRANS ( 'cx_login' ) ?>' tabindex='3'>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size:1.4em; line-height:1.7em">
    <a href="https://sigadmin.***.edu.br/admin/public/recuperar_login.jsf" target="_blank">Esqueci meu login</a><br>
    <a href="https://sigadmin.***.edu.br/admin/public/recuperar_senha.jsf" target="_blank">Esqueci minha senha</a><br>
    <a href="https://wiki.**.edu.br/index.php/Categoria:Abertura_de_Ocorr%C3%AAncias" target="_blank">Primeiro Acesso</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <a href="https://wiki.*****.edu.br" target="_blank">
  </div><br>
  <div class='grid_4' style="margin-top:10px; text-align: center;">
  <table>
  <tr><td style="padding-left:25px; line-height:1.4em !important;"><b>Antes de abrir um chamado, verifique se a solução do seu problema está na</b></td>
  <td rowspan="2"><img src="includes/imgs/wiki-unifesspa.jpg" width="100" height="100"></td></tr>
  </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 </a>
 </form>
 <?php }?>
```

o que coloco dentro da condicional pra ele trazer o formulario de novo ,deslogado e com outro aviso ??

```html
f (($_SESSION ['s_ocomon'] == 1) && ! isIn ( $_SESSION ['s_area'], $rowconf ['conf_ownarea_2'] )) {
  if ($_SESSION['s_nivel']==5){



(aqui)



    }
```

Comment: OBS: o primeiro código é o trecho que funciona , trata o login para senha e usuarios corretos

Comment: Se entendi bem, vc pode redirecionar ele para a tela de login com o `header('location')`....

Comment: Eu respondi algo muito parecido com sua pergunta esses dias https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207034/bloquear-p%C3%A1ginas-via-url/207063#207063 seria isso?